# Use jQuery variable within selector name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm grabbing the value of an input and setting this as a variable. How can I then use this as part of the selector name. Here's a demo of where I've got too and what I'm trying to achieve

```
    // grab the id   
    var rowId = $('input[name="row-id"]').val();

    // Use the variable as part of selector
    $('body').on("click", ".upload-form-'rowId'", function(event) { 

    // do stuff here  

    })
```

The output of the selector would be like .upload-form-99 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
// grab the id   
var rowId = $('input[name="row-id"]').val();

rowId = '.upload-form-' + rowId;

// Use the variable as part of selector
$('body').on("click", rowId, function(event) { 

// do stuff here  

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason that this wouldn't work?

```
$('body').on("click", ".upload-form-" + rowId, function...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elegant solution if you happen to be using ES6:

```js
    // grab the id   
   let rowId = $('input[name="row-id"]').val();

    // Use the variable as part of selector
    $('body').on("click", `.upload-form-${rowId}`, (event) => { 

    // do stuff here  

    })
```